# Elasticsearch Mapping and Settings definitions

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, analyzer

I tried setting a new index by configuring its mapping and settings.

Here is the code I used:

```
POST /test/text
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "greek_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_greek_" 
        },
        "greek_lowercase": {
          "type":       "lowercase",
          "language":   "greek"
        },
        "greek_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "greek"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "greek": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "greek_lowercase",
            "greek_stop",
            "greek_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "article": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "greek": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyser": "greek"
                }
              }
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "greek": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyser": "greek"
                }
              }
        },
        "indexed_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used POST as I didn't care much about the _id and that way ES gives a random value to this variable instead of using PUT where I have to specify its value. The reason why I created two fields for title and content is because I wish to have the raw version of text and the 'stop words removed-stemmed' version in order to be able to weight higher if the term is found exactly as the user entered it (instead of storing only the stemmed version of a word)

After populating the index with data, e.g.:

```
PUT /test/text
{
  "title": " ",
  "content": " ",
  "date": " "
}
```

I tried doing a search query like this:

```
GET /test/text/_search
{
    "query":{
        "multi_match":{
                "query":"όμορφος",
                "type":"most_fields",
                "fields":["content","content.greek","title","title.greek"]}}}
```

And then by changing the query to "όμορφη", these words have the same stemmed version which is "όμορφ", and as a result due to the ES's greek language analyzer I should get the same entry, which I don't.

Any idea why? Should I be doing something more while indexing my documents? After reading the documentation I was under the impression that after defining the mapping when indexing a piece of text it would automatically get indexed both ways and the query would each time be analysed using the appropriate analyzer automatically.

If I am under the right impression why my query doesn't return the same results? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the index in the first place you need to call `PUT test` not `POST /test/text`. The latter will simply create a new document of type `text` in a new index called `test`, but with the default settings and mappings.

So first:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    ...
  },
  "mappings": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can create new documents with (note that your mapping type was called `article`, not `text`)

```
POST /test/article
{
  "title": " ",
  "content": " ",
  "date": " "
}
```

Then only your search query will work

Comment: When I try to create an index with POST I get :
    {
      "_index": "test",
      "_type": "text",
      "_id": "AVfDJVLHvgDv319PJqTd",
      "_version": 1,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
      },
    "created": true
    }

On the other hand with PUT I get:
No handler found for uri [/test/article] and method [PUT]
Any idea why?
When I create /test instead of /test/text I get :

"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [analyser : greek]"

Comment: Since I do not wish to customise the greek analyser can I just do : 
"mappings": {
    "my_type_name": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }

instead of including this whole definition?

Comment: When creating the index, you MUST have `PUT` and only the name of your index. When creating a document, you can have either `POST index/type` or `PUT index/type/id`. Delete your index and start again with my proposal above.

Comment: When I tried that I got back:

     "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [analyser : greek]"
         }
      ]

Comment: That's a typo in your mapping, simply replace `analyser` by `analyzer`

Comment: I honestly cannot believe this. Nevertheless I found out about PUT and POST. Thank you for your help and really sorry for that damn typo.

Comment: No worries, glad we figured it out!

Comment: I managed to make it work and again thanks! If I may I would like to ask one last thing. Now that both analyzers work when I get a match on a query I get 2 results with approximately same score (e.g. 0.019558463 Vs 0.019007506) and on top fields are returned in different order per result in the source field (e.g. date,content vs content,date). Any idea why this happens?

Lastly when I use a stemmed word as query nothing works and I wonder why since using a language analyzer there should be a match there right? Thanks again I just thought to ask as you seem to know your way around ES. Cheers!

Comment: I would suggest to create a new question for this since this is a different issue.